# Dont get errors but my files don't upload to Google Storage

Tags: python, file-upload, google-cloud-storage, python-2.x

I've tried to upload files to GCS with my app (Python 2) but I have a problem, I dont get errors but my files dont upload to Google Storage, but for example I can delete files that I upload by hand. Do you know what could happen?

It works in local environment.

```
def upload_file(self, fileUpload, fileName):
"""Upload a file to GCS"""

pathFileGCS = "/" + get_bucket() + "/" + fileName

fileType = fileUpload.type
fileContent = fileUpload.file.read()

logging.info('WNP: Creando fichero %s de tipo %s en GCS', format(pathFileGCS), fileType)

fileGCS = gcs.open(pathFileGCS, 'w', content_type=fileType)
fileGCS.write(fileContent)
fileGCS.close
```

Comment: From what I understand, you are unable to upload *any of your files* using the Cloud Storage Python API. As there are many uncertainties from insufficient information at hand, such as where the `get_bucket()` function came from (I assume from a `storage.Client()` instance but I cannot say for sure that it has even been instantiated) it is difficult to solve this issue. Could you provide a [Minimal Working Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: In any case, I also suggest you look through this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-python) as it describes the necessary steps in order to upload files through the use of the Cloud Storage Python API.

Comment: Thanks @JKleinne, Im not solve the problem but I've changed to use google-cloud-storage and it works. In the example with the problem I was using GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient.

Comment: Glad everything worked out for you!

Answer (score 0):

Since it is running perfect locally and you take no errors, I would suggest you to make sure that you have included all the necessary requirements in the requirements.txt file.

Comment: I think that is not the problem because I can delete files in GAE but I cant upload files, there are no errors but the file doesn't upload. In local environment both of them operations works.